# Official Touch Screen not working with Raspberry pi B+

Tags: screen, touchscreen, pi-b+

So far, I've tried:

- turning it off and on again
- sudo apt-get update
- sudo apt-get upgrade
- sudo rpi-update
- rebooting
- disconnecting and reconnecting and checking the wiring

Still doesn't work.  What could be wrong?

Comment: Have you done a `sudo rpi-update` to download new firmware? The touch screen has a firmware update that needs to be installed, AFAIK.

Comment: @PhilB. I've done that.

Comment: And what happened?

Comment: Nothing.  Still the same blank screen.

Comment: Have you looked at `dmesg` or any of the kernel related logs in `/var/log`?

Comment: Did you plug it in before or after you turned on the Pi?