# Raspberry Pi 2 7" touchscreen display white screen error

Tags: pi-2, screen

I am making a tablet with a Raspberry Pi 2 Model B for a school project. The problem which I have is the screen is blank white. I have checked the wiring with the jumper cable, the ribbon cable is in correctly, and the copper connectors are fitted correctly. I believe it is a driver problem although I can not find any drivers for 7" display. and I would really appreciate if someone can answer my questions.[image: White screen error]

Comment: Is this the official RPi display?

Comment: "I am making a tablet with a Raspberry Pi 2 Model B for a school project." That is, frankly, a bad idea.  The raspberry pi's processor is intended for a set-top box with a line power supply, not mobile usage.  And it lacks an LCD interface for direct, native connection to a typical LCD which wants either parallel RGB, or in rare cases LVDS.  There's a reason tablets use the chips they do, and they aren't the one the pi uses.  But regardless of inefficiency, your question is not answerable without the *specifics* of the display *and interface board* being used.

Comment: Yes, this is the official RPi Display

Comment: I'm sure you must have followed official guide for running it. Posting it anyway. https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/the-eagerly-awaited-raspberry-pi-display/

Comment: Finally, I have gotten the screen to work, by re-assembling the Pi and flashing the Micro-SD card, thank you to all who help me solve this issue, Good luck to those who have this problem!

Answer (score 1):

> I believe it is a driver problem although I can not find any drivers for 7" display

That is not surprising if the only official documentation is this [near non-entity](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/the-eagerly-awaited-raspberry-pi-display/), which literally just says plug it in and run `apt-get get update`.

You are not the first person to have this problem and [report it here recently](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/37930/5538).  I searched through the Foundation's [documentation portal on github](https://github.com/raspberrypi/documentation) and "touchscreen" is barely mentioned.  From the troubleshooting page:

> *My touchscreen doesn't work, or works intermittently*
>
> - Make sure you've updated Raspbian, see above for steps.
> - Check the smaller ribbon cable is seated properly

Assuming you've done the first thing, which would be hard to get wrong without knowing it, make absolutely sure about the second one, which would be much easier to be mistaken about; I have done this the camera before.

If none of that works, post a comment on that blog/doc/announcement and ask for suggestions about debugging this problem.  At the very least, if enough people do that they make take notice.

You may also have better luck here by asking specifically what the name of the driver module for the board is, which would provide a clue about what to look for in logs, etc.