# White screen after the power on

Tags: pi-4, display, screen

I'm working on raspberry pi4 and 7" display.
When I start the raspberry, but after 3 seconds of black screen, it turns white.
I have already formatted the sd but the problem persist.
Which is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: *["I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?"](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)*

Answer (score 0):

Is it the official pi touch screen? If yes, it sounds similar to: [Raspberry Pi 2 7" touchscreen display white screen error](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/38397/raspberry-pi-2-7-touchscreen-display-white-screen-error?rq=1)

The OP solved it by re-flashing the SD card and re-seating the connections and ribbon.
You could check the card by plugging into another display.